# React component takes css from previous page

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react component in a project that I'm working on, and this component is on 2 different pages, and I gave it different css proprieties for each of these 2 pages.

**Now, the behaviour that I expect is** : when I switch the pages, the component will load the css that I gave for it for that specific page.

**What actually happens is** that if I switch between the pages, the component keeps some classes from the previous page, and messes up my component. If I manualy refresh the page, it loads only the css I expect, but If I just use my app buttons to switch between pages, without refresh, it does the unexpected behaviour.

Does anyone know why this happens ? Or how can I manage it ? I tried many css solutions, but none worked...

Comment: When you import `CSS` for any component, it gets imported for entire application. A workaround - change classname and use unique classnames for different styles

Comment: They have different classnames but this still happens

Comment: Then you may be targeting `HTML` elements directly, like applying styles on `img` or `a` tag instead of using classes

Comment: How did you solve this problem?